# Java: can i connect to database using my text file to specify user, password and url?

Tags: java, mysql

I am curious about making database connection in JAVA using my text file.

For example i create text file like this:

```
 user root
 passw root
 url http://localhost:3307/.........
```

Is there possible to connect to that database and get some info about it (time it was created all tables stored and etc.)

Comment: How do you want to connect a jdbc driver and phpmyadmin ? And I don't get what you want to do with this text file.

Comment: You probably should have a look at [`Driver#getConnection(String, Properties)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html#getConnection-java.lang.String-java.util.Properties-)

Comment: sorry made a mistake i think url should be like this no ?

Comment: good question btw , u could use bufferReader() store all data u scanned and put it to strings and later connect to your database

Comment: its similar use as EndNote where all connections stored in txt files but u must encrypt them because atackers could easily access it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you could easily do a real database connection:

- Load the file as lines
- split each line by " "
- put both values into a map
- when opening the connection via the JDBC driver, use the map's get(key) method to get the values (you could also connect using a (ssl)socket and lots of string parsing, but i'd suggest you use drivers)

**But** the actual problem you're facing here is: your URL points to a phpMyAdmin site running on an HTTP server, probably apache.
The URL will NOT give you the actual database.

Usually MySQL runs on port 3306.
From what it looks like, you're addressing the HTTP server on port 3307, which itself interprets the phpMyAdmin PHP files. Those order the HTTP server to connect to MySQL (probably on port 3306) and read certain infos.

So, using your given URL in a Java application would not be a real database connection, but just an HTTP request asking the the HTTP server for an HTML page that you might parse...

So you need to specify a lot more to actually get a final solutio to that problem.

/* EDIT */
Here's the example code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class SimpleTextFileDBConnectionConfig {

    //  MYSQL_DRIVER("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver", "jdbc:mysql://%host%:%port%/%dbname%?verifyServerCertificate=%vsc%&useSSL=%usessl%&requireSSL=%requiressl%"), //

    static public Connection getSimpleDBConnectionByTextFileConfig(final String pFileName) throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException, SQLException {
        final HashMap<String, String> settings = new HashMap<>();
        { // load settings from file; could also drop this in separate method
            final List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(pFileName));
            for (final String line : lines) {
                if (line == null || line.length() < 1 || line.startsWith("#")) continue; // ignore certain lines
                final String[] setting = line.trim().split(" ", 2);
                final String key = setting[0].trim();
                final String value = setting[1].trim();
                settings.put(key, value);
            }
        }

        // load driver
        final String driverName = settings.get("drivername"); // can be "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" for default java mysql driver
        Class.forName(driverName);

        // set timeout
        final String timeout = settings.get("timeout");
        if (timeout != null && timeout.length() > 0) DriverManager.setLoginTimeout(Integer.parseInt(timeout));

        // connect
        final String url = settings.get("url"); // can be like "jdbc:mysql://%host%:%port%/%dbname%?verifyServerCertificate=%vsc%&useSSL=%usessl%&requireSSL=%requiressl%"
        return DriverManager.getConnection(url, settings.get("user"), settings.get("password"));
    }

}
```

Comment: PLUS most properly configured mySQL servers would not allow connections from the internet, except cetain IP addresses. So trying to connect directly might not even be possible.

Comment: And what if i just read the data from txt and later using jdbc in java connect to database ?

Comment: Added the example code for you ;-)